# Showing a modal window multiple times using a non-blocking algorithm

Tags: javascript

I've an array in Javascript like this one

```
var myData = [{"UserName":"Foo", "info", {...} }, {"UserName":"Foo1", "info", {...} }];
```

Now I need to show a window (modal) showing the user name and the information contained in *info*

But I need to show an instance of the window for every item in *myData* ideally using a code like this

```
function ShowModalWindow() {
  var myData = [{"UserName":"Foo", "info", {...} }, {"UserName":"Foo1", "info", {...} }];

  myData.forEach(function (item) {
    window.ShowModal(item);
    // execution blocked until the window is closed
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

But I was reading about execution blocking in Javascript and it seems that it's not possible.

The question is How can I show more than one instance of the window without blocking the code execution?

**PD: I'm using a plugin that create the window. The way I create the window is not important here. The window is created in a non-blocking way.**

Comment: do you know about promises? I don't know if I understood your problem correctly, but I would use promises for that purpose - first modal spawns promise which resolved with second modal and so on. when all promises are resolved, callback is called

Comment: You can achieve this using an array of `Promises` and a library such as `async` and the `waterfall` function https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall

Comment: What is your `ShowModal()` function is returning ? is it a Promise ? Can you do `window.ShowModal(item).then(function() { /*...*/ })` ? What library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your plugin function gives you a `Promise`, you could use the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) (specially the [`waterfall` method](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall)) like that:

```
var myData = [{"UserName":"Foo", "info", {...} }, {"UserName":"Foo1", "info", {...} }];

// we create a array of functions
var modals = myData.map(function(item) {
  // we return a function that will load ShowModal
  // and call the callback function when it is closed
  return function(callback) {
    window.ShowModal(item).then(function(result) {
      // the Modal is closed, we call the callback 
      // with first argument null
      callback(null, result)
    }).catch(function(err) {
      // the Modal has been dismissed
      // we stop the execution by calling the callback
      // with a first argument
      callback(err)
    });
  }  
});

async.waterfall(modals,function (err, result) {
  if(err) return console.error(err)
  console.log('All done')
  console.log(result)
}
```

Note that if `ShowModal` does not return a promise, you could use the [`async.asyncify()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#asyncifyfunc) method to make it asynchronous:

```
async.asyncify(window.ShowModal(item)).then( function() {/*.. */})
```